# Promise method to wait 5 seconds once print out value

Tags: javascript

Currently creating a simple program to count back from 25 to 0. Each time it prints out the current value, the program should wait 5 seconds using a Promise(.then()) syntax. I'm a JS novice and just can't figure out how to do it in this specific way. Thanks so much.

```
count = 25;
while (count >= 0) {
  console.log(count).then(() => wait(7000));
  count = count - 1;
}
```

Comment: What you want to do can be accomplished without promises-- are promises somehow required?  Also, a promise can't be updated/resolved multiple times-- that sounds more like an observable...

Comment: Yes they are required for an assignment I'm doing. Thanks for the help.

Comment: To the down/close voters: I'm not saying this is a *great* question, but the aim is clear, the answer is not super complicated, and the OP at least wrote some code. How bad is it really? Just sayin...we all see a lot worse in the JS tag from new users...

Comment: @JaredSmith I downvoted and VTC it as too broad. They posted requirements, code that doesn't compile, and no clear description of what exactly they need help with. It's certainly answerable, but I don't believe this is an appropriate place for the question. They need general help.

Comment: @Carcigenicate your votes are of course to do with as you will and I'm not game to argue the point. If you still feel that way cool, I'm just suggesting that maybe we should think twice before pulling the trigger in this *specific* instance, I certainly would *not* try to argue that you're wrong.

Comment: @JaredSmith My initial vote was seeing this before a comment response was made. It's a broad question that isn't 100% clear on why it was asked. The comment reply makes it clear that this is a HW assignment and thus that specific bit should have been part of the question. Notice how there are now two completely different answers that technically are correct. However, only one of them satisfies the _actual_ question which wasn't immediately clear. Such broad questions that invite multiple ranging answers are generally not good questions in my opinion.

Comment: Feedback taken. I'll be more specific with my questions in the future.

Answer (score 6):

Well, you can't just attach `.then` to anything; that's just a method that you can chain onto Promises. `console.log` does not return a Promise, so you can't chain `.then` directly onto it. And Promises run asynchronously, meaning once you trigger one, it will do its thing while the code continues on; that's the point of Promises. So you can't put one inside a while loop and expect it to wait before continuing.

If you want to do this with Promises, instead you can use either async/await or construct an infinite Promise chain. I'd suggest the former.

So you'd first need to create your wait function, which should return a Promise that resolves after the specified amount of time:

```
function wait(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

Then you use an async function so you can make it await the Promises in each loop, though I'd suggest using a for loop instead of while since you have a set count of iterations:

```
async function DoLoop() {
  for (let count = 25; count >= 0; --count) {
    console.log(count);
    await wait(7000);
  }
}
```

Keep in mind, again, that async functions and Promises are, by definition, asynchronous, which means if you call the now-async DoLoop function somewhere, your code will continue running past that call while the loop is also running at the same time -- the code that called DoLoop won't wait for it to finish.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a version of the [answer of IceMetalPunk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57979363/3982562) without `async`/`await`.

```js
const wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

let chain = Promise.resolve();
for (let count = 25; count >= 0; --count) {
  chain = chain.then(() => {
    console.log(count);
    return wait(7000);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, no need for promises

Proof: https://jsfiddle.net/9f7rz2ck/2/

**Without promise** use setInterval to avoid looping through setTimeouts

```
let counter = 25;
let timer = setInterval(() => {
  --counter;
  console.log('Printing after 5 seconds', counter);
  if (counter === 0) {
    clearInterval(timer)
  }
}, 5 * 1000)
```

**With promise**, when a promise resolves it's over, you have to have 25 promises, therefore the loop.

```
let counter = 25;
function timeOut(i) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(--counter);
    }, 5 * 1000 * i)
  });
}
for (let i = 1; i <= 25; i++) {
  timeOut(i).then((x) => console.log('counter:', x))
}
```